# Can I use my Windows 7 CD key for a different language version?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with a CD key (English version) that came with my laptop.

I deleted my recovery partition by mistake. I got a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (Korean) version. Can I still use my Windows 7 English version CD key for the Home Premium Korean version?

Comment: Why don't you just download an English iso.  There is a question on this very website, that will let you do that, I don't trust strange domain websites.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot. The language needs to match. Even for ultimate, but you can change the language in ultimate after install